# When click a link in a link list generated by for loop, make the corresponding checkbox checked instead of the first checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have used Django to develop a web app. The front end used Django template engine.
In the HTML, a link list is generated by a for loop, before which a check box is shown corresponding to this link.
I want to achieve this: when click the link, the corresponding checkbox would be checked.
But now as I only has one id(in the loop I do not know how to generate different id in one line), o matter I click which link generated by the loop, always see the first checked box checked instead of the corresponding one.

HTML:

```
<td>{% for course in query_results %} <input type="checkbox" name="course" value=" {{course}}" id="addModal-body">
```

{{course}}
{% endfor %}

How to let the corresponding checkbox checked after click the link behind, instead of constantly see the first one being checked?

Comment: You may distinguish them with the `course_for_select` instance, with the `id` attribute. Or you can use `{{forloop.counter}}` inside the loop, which is a counter from 0 to the length of the iteration